# Filtering by the number of boolean occurrences per group in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm dealing with a Dataframe containing a column with a boolean data. This looks as follows:

```
       A  match
52     7   True
53     7   True
54     7   False
55     7   False
56     7   False
57     7   False
437    8   True
438    8   True
439    8   True
440    8   True
441    8   True
442    8   False
488    2   False
489    2   True
490    2   True
```

I need to remove that rows that present more than 2 False values in 'match' column, all in reference with column A. The output would be:

```
       A  match
437    8   True
438    8   True
439    8   True
440    8   True
441    8   True
442    8   False
488    2   False
489    2   True
490    2   True
```

I'm trying to groupby column A, then count the number of Falses but I'm stuck here. Some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negate your column, `groupby` `A`, and use `transform`:

```
s= (~df.match).groupby(df.A).transform('sum')
```

Next use `loc` to select desired values:

```
df.loc[s.le(2)]
```

```
     A  match 
437  8   True 
438  8   True 
439  8   True 
440  8   True 
441  8   True 
442  8  False 
488  2  False 
489  2   True 
490  2   True
```

In one line:

```
df.loc[(~df.match).groupby(df.A).transform('sum').le(2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter`

```
In [175]: df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: (~x.match).sum()<2)
Out[175]:
     A  match
437  8   True
438  8   True
439  8   True
440  8   True
441  8   True
442  8  False
488  2  False
489  2   True
490  2   True
```

Comment: Very nice but should it be <= 2, not <2?

Answer (score 1):

Using `isin` with `groupby` `sum`

```
s=(~df['match']).groupby(df['A']).sum()<2
df.loc[df.A.isin(s[s].index)]
Out[92]: 
     A  match
437  8   True
438  8   True
439  8   True
440  8   True
441  8   True
442  8  False
488  2  False
489  2   True
490  2   True
```